# How to select rows based on the combination of columns

Tags: r, select, dataframe, rows

I have the following data frame:

```
structure(list(Species = 1:4, Ni = c(1, NA, 1, 1), Zn = c(1, 
1, 1, 1), Cu = c(NA, NA, 1, NA)), .Names = c("Species", "Ni", 
"Zn", "Cu"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

and I would like to get a vector containing all the species where `Ni = 1`, `Zn = 1` and `Cu = NA`. So in this example that would be (1,4)

I thought I could have a try with the R script `select * from where`, but I can't seem to install the package RMySQL on RStudio (R version 2.15.1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df <- structure(list(Species=1:4,Ni=c(1,NA,1,1),Zn=c(1,1,1,1),Cu=c(NA,NA,1,NA)),
      .Names=c("Species","Ni","Zn","Cu"),row.names=c(NA,-4L),class="data.frame")

with(df, Species[Ni %in% 1 & Zn %in% 1 & Cu %in% NA])
[1] 1 4
```

Rather than using `Ni == 1` you should use `Ni %in% 1`, as the former will return `NA` elements where `Ni` is `NA`. `Cu %in% NA` produces the same result as `is.na(Cu)`.

```
with(df, Species[Ni == 1 & Zn %in% 1 & Cu %in% NA])
[1] 1 NA 4
```

Note though that `Ni == 1` used in `subset`, as in @MadScone's answer, does not suffer from this (which came as a surprise to me).

```
subset(df, Ni == 1 & Zn == 1 & is.na(Cu), Species)
  Species
1       1
4       4
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at subset().

```
x <- structure(list(Species = 1:4, Ni = c(1, NA, 1, 1), Zn = c(1, 
     1, 1, 1), Cu = c(NA, NA, 1, NA)), .Names = c("Species", "Ni", 
     "Zn", "Cu"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

subset(x, Ni == 1 & Zn == 1 & is.na(Cu), Species)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
I stand corrected by `Backlin`...
**It is *much* better** to use `%in%` rather than `== x & !is.na()` !
`MadScone`'s suggestion of using `subset()` **is better yet**, since the result remains a data.frame, even when one select only one column for the output, i.e.

```
> class(subset(df, Ni == 1 & Zn == 1 & is.na(Cu), Species))
[1] "data.frame"
#whereby we get a vector when only one column is selected...
> class(df[df$Ni %in% 1 & df$Zn %in% 1 & is.na(df$Cu), 1])
[1] "integer"
# but we get data.frame when using multiple columns...
> class(df[df$Ni %in% 1 & df$Zn %in% 1 & is.na(df$Cu), 1:2])
[1] "data.frame"
```

---

I'm just leaving my sub-par answer to mention this alternative idiom, *as one one should avoid*!

Setup:

```
>  df <- structure(list(Species = 1:4, Ni = c(1, NA, 1, 1), Zn = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1), Cu = c(NA, NA, 1, NA)), .Names = c("Species", "Ni", 
    "Zn", "Cu"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
> df
  Species Ni Zn Cu
1       1  1  1 NA
2       2 NA  1 NA
3       3  1  1  1
4       4  1  1 NA
```

Query:

```
>  df[df$Ni == 1 & !is.na(df$Ni) 
      & df$Zn == 1 & !is.na(df$Zn) 
      & is.na(!df$Cu), ]

  Species Ni Zn Cu
 1       1  1  1 NA
 4       4  1  1 NA
```

The trick with NA values is to explicitly exclude them i.e. for example with Ni, request value 1 and !is.na() etc.  Failure to do so results in finding records where, say, Ni is NA

**As mentioned above the  `df[df$Ni %in% 1 & df$Zn %in% 1 & is.na(!df$Cu), ]` idiom is much preferable and using subset() is typically better yet.**

```
> df[df$Ni == 1 & df$Zn == 1 & is.na(!df$Cu), ]
   Species Ni Zn Cu
1        1  1  1 NA
NA      NA NA NA NA       # OOPS...
4        4  1  1 NA
```

Comment: Is there an advantage of doing `== & !is.na` instead of just `%in%`? To me it just looks messier. Btw, she only wants the `Species` column.

Comment: No worries! I love `%in%`, hardly do `==` since I found it.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- structure(list(Species = 1:4, Ni = c(1, NA, 1, 1), Zn = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
                     Cu = c(NA, NA, 1, NA)),
                .Names = c("Species", "Ni", "Zn", "Cu"), row.names = c(NA, -4L),
                class = "data.frame")
```

If the columns `Ni`, `Zn`, and `Cu` contain `1` and `NA` only, you could simply use:

```
subset(df, Ni & Zn & is.na(Cu), Species)
```